# Android not letting app install

Tags: android, installation

I'm running a beta test and hence loaded the apk to a public URL (Amazon S3). Until this point the URL was not public domain.

I installed the app on multiple devices and after a day or two, I'm getting the popup warning to uninstall the app. Pop up displays message as "Uninstall the is app immediately" and "It can let people control your device without approval"

[pop up image url](http://www.adfiles.in/error.jpg)

And this behavior is not the same on all the phones/devices.  On virustotal, I'm getting 1/57 detection ratio where drweb is giving this message - Android.Gmuse.2.origin. but this error from virustotal comes for my previous apps I've created also - but not this uninstall warning from Android and my apps are running fine on many other devices.

If it helps, I've also listed the permissions my app is using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Share App -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.apps.corecomponents.view.TAB_INFO" />

<permission
    android:name="com.apps.corecomponents.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission android:name="com.apps.corecomponents.view.TAB_INFO" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.apps.corecomponents.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Please let me know what prompts this error and how do we fix it?

Comment: Does your app really need all these permissions?

Comment: I need it because my app has many features which require such permissions

Answer (score 0):

With app verification turned on, your device will verify apps when you install them, as well as periodically scan for potentially harmful apps.

Verify at app installation

With app verification turned on, your device will do one of the following when you try to install an app outside of Google Play:

Recommend that you do not install the app
Block the installation of the app completely if there is a security threat to your device
When you try to install an app, your device may send information to Google identifying the app, including log information, URLs related to the app, device ID, your OS version, and IP address.

Scan for harmful apps on your device

When app verification is turned on, the installed apps on your device are periodically scanned. If a potentially harmful app is detected, verify apps may take the follow action:

Recommend that you immediately uninstall the app
Remove an app that is known to be unsafe from your device